# Windows DIR command searches folders it shouldn't

Tags: windows-7, windows, cmd.exe, dir

I'm trying to create a batch file that searches certain folders on our server for JPGs and creates a txt file with them. It works fine BUT for some reason it always adds a folder to the end of the list that I never asked it to search.

My batch looks like this:

`chcp 1252`
`dir "\\kahlaf1\bilddateien\4_digitalbildkatalog" *.jpg /O:EG /S /B > "\\kahlaf1\Bilddateien\Batchdatei\Bilder.txt"`
`dir "\\kahlaf1\bilddateien\12_dekoranlagen" *.jpg /O:EG /S /B >> "\\kahlaf1\Bilddateien\Batchdatei\Bilder.txt"`
`dir "\\kahlaf1\Fotos OXAION" *.jpg /O:EG /S /B >> "\\kahlaf1\Bilddateien\Batchdatei\Bilder.txt"`

Three specific folders as you can see. The .txt however adds a whole bunch of C:\Windows\ folders at the end for no apparent reason:

C:\Windows\Globalization\MCT\MCT-AU\Wallpaper\AU-wp2.jpg
C:\Windows\Globalization\MCT\MCT-AU\Wallpaper\AU-wp3.jpg
C:\Windows\Globalization\MCT\MCT-AU\Wallpaper\AU-wp4.jpg
 [...]
C:\Windows\System32\oobe\Info\Backgrounds\BACKGROUND1024X600.JPG
C:\Windows\System32\oobe\Info\Backgrounds\BACKGROUND1024X768.JPG
C:\Windows\System32\oobe\Info\Backgrounds\BACKGROUND1280X1024.jpg

And so forth.

Doesn't matter if I run the .bat from my local computer or a server folder either.

Answer (score 1):

You've got the quotes wrong. This

`dir "\kahlaf1\bilddateien\4_digitalbildkatalog" *.jpg /O:EG /S /B`

lists *both* `"\kahlaf1\bilddateien\4_digitalbildkatalog\*.*"` *and* `.\*.jpg`. Try instead

```
dir "\kahlaf1\bilddateien\4_digitalbildkatalog\*.jpg" /O:EG /S /B`
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That solved the problem. Shoulda have figured that one out myself.